# Handle app closing events with active GUI updates

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am working on a WinForms C# app that has some potentially long-running cleanup activities. I would like to present the user status updates on the cleanup activities after the close button is clicked, but it appears that any updates to the GUI are not processed in the FormClosing() event.

e.g.

```
private void MyApp_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    lblMainStatus.Text = "Closing app, please wait.";
    foreach(MyResource r in AppResources)
    {
        lblMinorStatus.Text = "Freeing resources - remaining : " + AppResources.Count;
        r.discard();
    }
    lblMinorStatus.Text = "Done.";
    // And so on...
}
```

Any ideas? The only thing I can think of is to remove the 'X' close button on the window and instead close through a menu item or custom close button in the app but I would prefer to leave the standard close button active. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can call the label's Update() method to force it to paint.  That will work for a handful of seconds.  Do consider not making the user wait for this by running this on a thread.  Or not bother at all if the program terminates right after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is instead of label you provide messagebox or you can do like this...

```
private void MyApp_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    lblMainStatus.Text = "Closing app, please wait.";
    foreach(MyResource r in AppResources)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        lblMinorStatus.Text = "Freeing resources - remaining : " + AppResources.Count;
        r.discard();
        this.Refresh();
    }
    lblMinorStatus.Text = "Done.";
    // And so on...
}
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick. I added this.Refresh() after each update and it displayed the updated status messages.

Comment: Nice, but it forces the user to wait a second by loop iteration: I think a smaller sleep value could also work.

Answer (score 0):

You are should probably force a `.Refresh()` to ensure labels are up to date. However, if you are doing lots of things on exit you could do something like this (not at computer with VS so please check for typos etc as not compile checked):

```
private bool _applicationReadyToExit = false;

// ... Your project code here ...

private void MyApp_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_applicationReadyToExit)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        CleanAndExit();
        return;
    }
}

private void CleanAndExit()
{
    lblMainStatus.Text = "Closing app, please wait.";
    lblMainStatus.Refresh();

    foreach(MyResource r in AppResources)
    {
        lblMinorStatus.Text = "Freeing resources - remaining : " + AppResources.Count;
        lblMinorStatus.Refresh();
        r.discard();
    }
    lblMinorStatus.Text = "Done.";
    lblMinorStatus.Refresh();

    // And so on... Then close informing that we are clean
    _applicationReadyToExit = true;
    this.Close();
}
```

That way you can call `CleanAndExit()` from a menu or button click etc as well as if the user clicks the X.

Comment: You're close here, but you need to run `CleanAndExit` in a non-UI thread for this general approach to work, and then you need a means of reporting the progress to the UI thread.  The use of `Refresh` here does nothing; you're blocking the UI thread so the application will still be not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Some controls will get updated while FormClosing and some will not.
It's probably easiest to call Refresh on the form when needed that way all controls should get updated.

```
private void MyApp_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  lblMainStatus.Text = "Closing app, please wait.";
  MyApp.Refresh();

  foreach(MyResource r in AppResources)
  {
    lblMinorStatus.Text = "Freeing resources - remaining : " + AppResources.Count;
    r.discard();
    MyApp.Refresh();
  }

  lblMinorStatus.Text = "Done.";
  MyApp.Refresh();
  // And so on...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to add `lblMinorStatus.Refresh();` after `lblMinorStatus.Text = ...`.

Comment: Could the downvoter elaborate? Although this answer might not work as expected, it gives the idea.